# Framework making easy GUI in J2EE

Tags: jakarta-ee, user-interface, frameworks

I'm new to Java EE web application development. I need to develop a MVC web application with spring, hibernate and MySQL. Currently I'm stuck with the choice of a framework that will help me to develop GUIs.

I had experience with Android applications, where we just need XML files in the res\layout and the corresponding java classes in the src file. Can you provide me please with the closest Java EE framework?

Comment: Please note it's Java EE now and not J2EE anymore. Please update your knowledge.

Comment: @MikeBraun thnx I edited my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could look at jsf or jsp, but if you want my honest answer, just use html/jQuery and css, with Spring MVC acting as basically a restful endpoint.

This will give you the advantage of any cool UI stuff you want to will be easy to find examples or easy to get help with if you get stuck.  If it's some dark combination of say liferay with some other bizarre incantation it'll just be a pain.

If you want an example to work from, I released an open source spring mvc application [www.playerviewer.com](http://www.playerviewer.com) [here](https://github.com/david99world/ESPNPlayerViewer).  That's just a really simple jQuery + springMVC app that should give you an idea.

Answer (score 1):

If you wan't something similar to Android I think that JSF with facelets (not jsp) is your best option. JSF has very good component libraries with lots of components/widgets that will increase your productivity. If it's an option, I'd try to go with JSF 2.2. One big advantage of JSF 2.2 is good html 5 support.

**Simlarities to Android:**

- You define your pages using xml.
- You can use controller beans which can be compared to Activity classes that can suppy your view with dynamic data and access the instances of your components and programatically change the view
- There are standard UI components/widgets
- You can extend new components and create composites of the standard components

**Differences from Android:**

- The JSF lifecycle is very different from Android (but you can acheive quite a lot in JSF without knowing the lifecycle)
- JSF allows some logic in your xml file through its expression language (EL).
- You have to start thinking in terms of what happens on the server side and what happens on the client side (general for all web programming)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Simon, JSF with Facelets would be your best choice.

Naturally there are differences between a web app and a mobile/desktop app, but the way in which you lay out components in an .xhtml file and bind those components to their data input/ouput is pretty similar.

Do take a look at some component libraries, especially PrimeFaces. OmniFaces is a valuable addition as well to JSF.

The easiest way to get started with JSF is to use a server that already has JSF build-in. TomEE, GlassFish and JBoss are good examples. These servers also give you things like bean validation which works really great with JSF.